# Using Young Diagram to show the number of partitions of n is equal to number of partitions of 2n into n parts

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, proof-explanation

Show that the number of partitions of the integer $n$ is equal to the number of partitions of $2n$ into $n$ parts using a Young Diagram.

I can't seem to figure out any way to create a bijection between these two cases using a Young Diagram.

I'm thinking to maybe create a diagram of the "$n$ into anything" part and then adding an extra row on the bottom of that of length $n$ to create the second half.

Does this work?

Comment: Consider a partition of $n$. Let's pretend that it has exactly $n$ parts (indeed, it can't have more than $n$; if it has less, then just pad it with $0$s). Add $1$ to each part. What do you get?

Comment: Yours is a special case of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629534/of-partitions-of-n-into-at-most-r-positive-integers-of-partitions-of).